# Cant find extension installed in azure web apps

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, composer-php

I have configured an azure web app for PHP with windows OS. I have installed "composer" (for PHP) extension through azure portal and I can see the extension installed.
I can access the batch file when I traverse to the path as well but when I search "where composer" from global paths, then it cant be found. What am I missing? Do I need to add this to env paths somewhere?

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you checked this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azure-web-sites-extensions/

Comment: Yes @SaiSakethGuduru-MT, I have added the extension through the portal itself

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing? Do I need to add this to env paths somewhere?

No, env path is required. To test this i have created a webapp (PHP 7.4, running on windows OS) and ran the below `WHERE` cmdlet in the below format and able to find the installed extension.

```
WHERE /R c:\home\SiteExtensions *.bat or WHERE /R c:\home\SiteExtensions composer*
```

***Here is the sample output screenshot for reference:***

[image]

Comment: That's what my understanding is. Though, that is not working on my web app. Added another image above

Comment: @PetriNetTechnologies Can you try running any of the cmdlets(that were provided by me in answer section and see) whether you are able to get the path of that composer extension and also add the screenshots as well